# how to create a folder in google drive, using curl in shell

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to upload a zip file to Google drive account using curl.
Before uploading , i need to create a folder using curl  and to  that folder i need to upload the zipped file

i uploaded the file using the link - [upload zip file to google drive using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878753/upload-zip-file-to-google-drive-using-curl)

Comment: How to create a folder on Google Drive using curl in shell

Comment: A folder is a file with the MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` and with no extension. To upload a file under the folder, you need to specify `parents: [folderId]` in the metadata field of the multipart/resumable file upload request. Read Google drive API guide for more information. (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder)