# how to get token.txt for google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I read the content from

[upload zip file to google drive using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878753/upload-zip-file-to-google-drive-using-curl)

but stackoverflow forbidden me to comment under the answer of the link.

What I want to know is:

how the get the token.txt mentioned in above link?

Much Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to the Google Drive API using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373520/how-to-connect-to-the-google-drive-api-using-curl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that answer, the token mentioned is the user authorization token. You manage them when using [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authenticate your users. You can read the docs to get more information about [how to authorize your users with the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) (and subsequently to create and manage tokens).